# Primes in an extension over Dedekind domain

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I am considering Dedekind domain $\mathbb{Z}[a]/(a^3-a-1)$. I consider the splitting of $23\in \mathbb{Z}$. I know from Daniel Marcas, that if $Q$ is a prime dividing $23$ in the extension, them $Q\cap \mathbb{Z}=(23)$. I need to prove $(23,a-3)$ is a prime dividing $23$, in $\mathbb{Z}[a]/(a^3-a-1)$. Clearly, $(23,a-3)\cap \mathbb{Z}=(23)$. So, does it proves that it is a prime over $23$?

Comment: In any Dedekind domain, If you have a containment of ideals $I\subseteq J$ then there exists an ideal $K$ with $I=JK$.  Clearly $(23)\subseteq (23,a-3)$.  Hence $(23,a-3)$ divides $(23)$.

Comment: Sorry - your question was is $(23,a-3)$ a prime.  To see that it is, just quotient your ring by it, to get $\mathbb{F}_{23}[a]/(a^3-a-1,a-3)$.  As $(a-3)| a^3-a-1$ you have that this quotient equals $\mathbb{F}_{23}[a]/(a-3)=\mathbb{F}_{23}$.  Now $\mathbb{F}_{23}$ is a field, hence an integral domain.  Thus $(23,a-3)$ is indeed a prime.  From my previous comment you know it divides $(23)$.

Comment: @tkf: Why $(a-3)\,|\,(a^3-a-1)$?

Comment: @Berci If you substitute in $a=3$ to $a^3-3-1$ you get $27-3-1=23\equiv 0 \mod 23$.  I should have stated explicitly that we are working modulo $23$ here, but it is reasonably clear from context.

Comment: @tkf : So, from your comment I conclude for a general Dedekind domain $\mathbb{Z}[a]/(g(a))$, $(23,f(a))$ is a prime iff, $f(a)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{23}$ and if $g(a)$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{23}$ then $f(a)\mid g(a)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{23}$. Is it correct?

Comment: $(23,f(a))$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[a]/(g(a))$ iff $\gcd(f(a),g(a))$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{23}$.  This does not require $f(a)$ to be irreducible.  Conversely it is not implied by $f(a),g(a)$ both being irreducible.  What is true, is that if $f(a)$ is irreducible and $f(a)|g(a)$ then $(23,f(a))$ is prime.

Comment: But $f(a),g(a)$ both irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{23}$, does imply $\mathbb{F}_{23}[a]/(f(a),g(a))$ is a field, by that logic $(23,f(a))$ should be a prime right?

Comment: No $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ may both be irreducible and coprime, $((f(a),g(a))=(1)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you help, I got your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove that $(23,a-3)$ is a proper ideal (ie. not containing $1$). Then $(23,a-3)\cap \Bbb{Z}$ is a proper ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ containing $23$ so it has to be $(23)$.

The proof will follow from that $\mathbb{Z}[a]/(a^3-a-1)/(23,a-3)\cong \Bbb{F}_{23}[x]/(x^3-x-1,x-3)\cong \Bbb{F}_{23}[x]/(x-3)\cong \Bbb{F}_{23}$. The latter is a field thus $(23,a-3)$ was a maximal ideal.